# compare variables didn't always work correctly

Tags: bash, quotes

I have a function in utils.sh file

```
function contains_elt() {

    local -n ARRAY=$1
    local ELT=$2
    contains_elt_res=false

    local i
    for i in "${!ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        echo "$i === $ELT"
        if [ $i = $ELT ] ; then
            echo "Elt $ELT exists"
            contains_elt_res=true
        fi
    done
}
```

called in main script file inside another function :

```
function verify_lib_existance() {
    local -n array=$1

    if [ ${#array[@]} = 0 ] ; then
        printf "${RED} libs can not be empty.${NC}\n"
        exit 1
    fi

    local i
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo "elet = $i"
        contains_elt LIBS $i

        if [ $contains_elt_res = false ] ; then
            printf "${RED} the lib ${i} is not support right now.${NC}\n"
            printf "${GREEN}Please add it in the LIBS array in utils.sh file ${NC}:\n"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}
```

the problem is inside the first function, and exactly in the if statement, the comparison is not stable, when I get my inputs with **read**, sometime it works correctly and sometimes not, and you see the line before the if, I place an echo and I see that the value is the same but if didn't work correctly.

Comment: Check your value for whitespace, carriage returns, ansi escapes, and similar. These all cause `echo` to show the same output, even though the values are different.

Comment: Please add a shebang to your code and then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1):

Surround all your variable references with double quotes.

```sh
function contains_elt() {
    local -n ARRAY="$1"
    local ELT="$2"
    contains_elt_res=false

    local i
    for i in "${!ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        echo "$i === $ELT"
        if [ "$i" = "$ELT" ] ; then
            echo "Elt $ELT exists"
            contains_elt_res=true
        fi
    done
}

function verify_lib_existance() {
    local -n array="$1"

    if [ "${#array[@]}" = 0 ] ; then
        printf "${RED} libs can not be empty.${NC}\n"
        exit 1
    fi

    local i
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo "elet = $i"
        contains_elt LIBS "$i"

        if [ "$contains_elt_res" = false ] ; then
            printf "${RED} the lib ${i} is not support right now.${NC}\n"
            printf "${GREEN}Please add it in the LIBS array in utils.sh file ${NC}:\n"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: I already try this but always the same problem. what do you think if I add the whole two files and so you can test ?

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion that @Cyrus made?